# Connect Cognos Power Play Transforme to a Data Source

Tags: oracle10g, cognos, cognos-bi

First off I'm completely new to Cognos; and I'm being requested to find out how can I connect the PowerPlay Transformer 7.3 application to an Oracle 10.2 Datasource, from what I've researched so far there is no direct way to do this I need to have a Cognos BI Server.

Can someone please give me more info on this topic.

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prepare an .iqd-file using Impromptu or Framework Manager.
This kind of file describes how to connect to database.
Or you can export your data to text file from Oracle and use it directly

Comment: I suppose these are additional tools right? I don't heve them installed is there any additional option or it's a must to raise a ticket asking for the installation of the applications?

Comment: Yes. Cognos Impromptu and Cognos Framework Manager are additional tools. AFAIR you can edit IQD files manually. But I don't remember iqd-file format.

Comment: Or you can get iqd from somebody who have FM or Impromptu. This person should be in the same environment, you should have access to same servers. And don't forget to add a proper row to cognos.ini file.